# Is it possible stitch together images in swift?

Tags: swift, image

For example, could I take image A and image B to create an image C that contains both images side by side?

Comment: Sure it is possible.

Comment: As far as I know Swift does not have native image formats or image manipulation functions. This is really more of a platform question. Mac OS and iOS both have frameworks to do that. @ajeferson  posted an answer using the Cocoa Touch framework for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it is. The following code results in two images stitched side by side:

```
// This rect is where your resulting image goes
let resultingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resultingRect.size, false, 1)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context?.interpolationQuality = .high

// Drawing left image
let leftImage = UIImage(named: "pikachu.jpg")!
let leftRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
leftImage.draw(in: leftRect)


// Drawing right image
let rightImage = UIImage(named: "pikachu.jpg")!
let rightRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
rightImage.draw(in: rightRect)

// Get image from current context
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
imageView.image = newImage
```

Of course there are a lot of options with which you can play around and should take a look, but this a good starting point.

Comment: Note that you've assumed iOS, which is not necessarily the asker's platform.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're right, my bad. Thanks for pointing it out.